# Difference between DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE and DRUPAL_NO_CACHE

Tags: routes, caching, blocks

What is the difference between **DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE** and **DRUPAL_NO_CACHE**?

I'm developing a module that will generate 2 blocks for menu and it's sub-menu in different blocks and can't decide between those two options for the blocks.

**links:**
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/constant/DRUPAL_NO_CACHE/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/constant/DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE/7

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! What don't you understand in "The block or element can change depending on the page being viewed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `DRUPAL_NO_CACHE` doesn't cache the item, ever.
- `DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE` caches the item per page url -- this is useful for example if the block changes with a url context.

Comment: What means `caches the item per page url`?

Comment: It means that, if you visit twice a page like node/1 and the block is visibile on those pages, the second time the block will be rendered from the cache.

Comment: thanks, I think I could use DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE in this case